# How can I calculate the last line width of label?

Tags: ios, swift, label, uilabel

```
private func getLasLineWidth() -> CGFloat {

    let message = NSAttributedString(string: self.text!,
                                     attributes: [.font: self.font!])

    let labelWidth = self.bounds.width
    // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
    let labelSize = CGSize(width: labelWidth, height: .infinity)
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: labelSize)
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: message)

    // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
     layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

    // Configure textContainer
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0

    let lastGlyphIndex = layoutManager.glyphIndexForCharacter(at: message.length - 1)
    let lastLineFragmentRect = layoutManager.lineFragmentUsedRect(forGlyphAt: lastGlyphIndex,
                                                                  effectiveRange: nil)

    return lastLineFragmentRect.maxX
}
```

I have tried this line of code, and it's not working for orientation landscape. How can I fix this problem? Does anyone have this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like the issue is due to the fact that your `getLasLineWidth()` func is not taking into account the paragraph styling you're setting.

You *may* be able to fix the problem by changing this:

```
func getLasLineWidth() -> CGFloat {

    let message = NSAttributedString(string: self.text!,
                                     attributes: [.font: self.font!])
```

to this:

```
func getLasLineWidth() -> CGFloat {

    guard let message = self.attributedText else { return CGFloat.zero }
```

I've only done some quick testing, but it looks like this should do it.